# SIGABRT error when returning from C++ code from java module in android

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

Still new to android and java but learning more each day :)

[This question refers to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73941988/yet-another-how-to-call-c-method-from-java-have-added-to-project-and-compiles?noredirect=1#comment130585346_73941988)

Ok, the error refers to

> expression failed to parse:
> error: <user expression 27>:1:1: 'bl' has unknown type; cast it to its declared type to use it
> bl
> ^~
> and

> expression failed to parse:
> error: <user expression 28>:1:1: 'uxtb' has unknown type; cast it to its declared type to use it
> uxtb.w
> ^~~~

I call (will want a short ) `result = getCheckSum(A, B);` from my java code.

The method in my C++ code is

```
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
unsigned short ekmCheckCRC16(const unsigned char *dat, unsigned short len)
{
    unsigned short crc = 0xffff;

    while (len--)
    {
        crc = (crc >> 8 ) ^ ekmCrcLut[(crc ^ *dat++) & 0xff];
    }

    crc = (crc << 8 ) | (crc >> 8);
    crc &= 0x7f7f;

    return crc;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Implementation of the native method getCheckSum()
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT unsigned short JNICALL
Java_com_(...)_getCheckSum(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jstring a) {
    const char * aCStr = env->GetStringUTFChars(a, NULL);
    if(NULL == aCStr)
        return NULL;
    unsigned  short crc = ekmCheckCRC16(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>(aCStr), strlen(aCStr));

    return crc;

}
```

This code is experimental showing the actual code I want to run ekmCheckCRC16( ... ), its purpose is to learn how to return a value back to the java module.

The error message seems to be clear 'unknown' type cast, so question is, how should I be returning the value of aCStr?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html for a list of available primitive types.

Comment: @Michael, I have everything sorted out now, just posted an answer, it was my bad and at end of day, JNI is not that hard to implement, have learnt heaps from this, cheers

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem, was simple error of not changing one important detail before executing call i was looking for a return type of short but had String in native declaration.

I had
`private native String getCheckSum(String a);`

it should have been

```
    `private native short getCheckSum(String a);`
```

My call was / is

short result = getCheckSum(A);

Worked fine after correcting my mistake.

for those interested my c++ code

```
    #include <jni.h>       // JNI header provided by JDK
#include "ekmCheckSum.h"
#include <iostream>    // C++ standard IO header
using namespace std;

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 void ekmCheckSum() {

}

static const unsigned short ekmCrcLut[256] = {
    0x0000, 0xc0c1, 0xc181, 0x0140, 0xc301, 0x03c0, 0x0280, 0xc241,
    0xc601, 0x06c0, 0x0780, 0xc741, 0x0500, 0xc5c1, 0xc481, 0x0440,
    0xcc01, 0x0cc0, 0x0d80, 0xcd41, 0x0f00, 0xcfc1, 0xce81, 0x0e40,
    0x0a00, 0xcac1, 0xcb81, 0x0b40, 0xc901, 0x09c0, 0x0880, 0xc841,
    0xd801, 0x18c0, 0x1980, 0xd941, 0x1b00, 0xdbc1, 0xda81, 0x1a40,
    0x1e00, 0xdec1, 0xdf81, 0x1f40, 0xdd01, 0x1dc0, 0x1c80, 0xdc41,
    0x1400, 0xd4c1, 0xd581, 0x1540, 0xd701, 0x17c0, 0x1680, 0xd641,
    0xd201, 0x12c0, 0x1380, 0xd341, 0x1100, 0xd1c1, 0xd081, 0x1040,
    0xf001, 0x30c0, 0x3180, 0xf141, 0x3300, 0xf3c1, 0xf281, 0x3240,
    0x3600, 0xf6c1, 0xf781, 0x3740, 0xf501, 0x35c0, 0x3480, 0xf441,
    0x3c00, 0xfcc1, 0xfd81, 0x3d40, 0xff01, 0x3fc0, 0x3e80, 0xfe41,
    0xfa01, 0x3ac0, 0x3b80, 0xfb41, 0x3900, 0xf9c1, 0xf881, 0x3840,
    0x2800, 0xe8c1, 0xe981, 0x2940, 0xeb01, 0x2bc0, 0x2a80, 0xea41,
    0xee01, 0x2ec0, 0x2f80, 0xef41, 0x2d00, 0xedc1, 0xec81, 0x2c40,
    0xe401, 0x24c0, 0x2580, 0xe541, 0x2700, 0xe7c1, 0xe681, 0x2640,
    0x2200, 0xe2c1, 0xe381, 0x2340, 0xe101, 0x21c0, 0x2080, 0xe041,
    0xa001, 0x60c0, 0x6180, 0xa141, 0x6300, 0xa3c1, 0xa281, 0x6240,
    0x6600, 0xa6c1, 0xa781, 0x6740, 0xa501, 0x65c0, 0x6480, 0xa441,
    0x6c00, 0xacc1, 0xad81, 0x6d40, 0xaf01, 0x6fc0, 0x6e80, 0xae41,
    0xaa01, 0x6ac0, 0x6b80, 0xab41, 0x6900, 0xa9c1, 0xa881, 0x6840,
    0x7800, 0xb8c1, 0xb981, 0x7940, 0xbb01, 0x7bc0, 0x7a80, 0xba41,
    0xbe01, 0x7ec0, 0x7f80, 0xbf41, 0x7d00, 0xbdc1, 0xbc81, 0x7c40,
    0xb401, 0x74c0, 0x7580, 0xb541, 0x7700, 0xb7c1, 0xb681, 0x7640,
    0x7200, 0xb2c1, 0xb381, 0x7340, 0xb101, 0x71c0, 0x7080, 0xb041,
    0x5000, 0x90c1, 0x9181, 0x5140, 0x9301, 0x53c0, 0x5280, 0x9241,
    0x9601, 0x56c0, 0x5780, 0x9741, 0x5500, 0x95c1, 0x9481, 0x5440,
    0x9c01, 0x5cc0, 0x5d80, 0x9d41, 0x5f00, 0x9fc1, 0x9e81, 0x5e40,
    0x5a00, 0x9ac1, 0x9b81, 0x5b40, 0x9901, 0x59c0, 0x5880, 0x9841,
    0x8801, 0x48c0, 0x4980, 0x8941, 0x4b00, 0x8bc1, 0x8a81, 0x4a40,
    0x4e00, 0x8ec1, 0x8f81, 0x4f40, 0x8d01, 0x4dc0, 0x4c80, 0x8c41,
    0x4400, 0x84c1, 0x8581, 0x4540, 0x8701, 0x47c0, 0x4680, 0x8641,
    0x8201, 0x42c0, 0x4380, 0x8341, 0x4100, 0x81c1, 0x8081, 0x4040
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
unsigned short ekmCheckCRC16(const unsigned char *dat, unsigned short len)
{
    unsigned short crc = 0xffff;

    while (len--)
    {
        crc = (crc >> 8 ) ^ ekmCrcLut[(crc ^ *dat++) & 0xff];
    }

    crc = (crc << 8 ) | (crc >> 8);
    crc &= 0x7f7f;

    return crc;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Implementation of the native method getCheckSum()
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT unsigned short JNICALL
Java_com_[project name]_ekmV4Fields_getCheckSum(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jstring a) {
    const char * aCStr = env->GetStringUTFChars(a, NULL);
    if(NULL == aCStr)
        return NULL;
    unsigned  short crc = ekmCheckCRC16(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>(aCStr), strlen(aCStr));

    return crc;

}
```

my .h file contains

```
    #ifndef PROJECT_NAME_EKMCHECKSUM_H
#define PROJECT_NAME_EKMCHECKSUM_H

class ekmCheckSum
    {
    private:
    public:
        ekmCheckSum();
        unsigned short ekmCheckCRC16(const unsigned char *dat, unsigned short len);
  };

#endif //PROJECT_NAME_EKMCHECKSUM_H
```

my java file includes

```
 static {System.loadLibrary("ekmCheckSum");}
    
    private native short getCheckSum(String a);
    
    public void SetEkmFieldValueStrings(String A, String B)
      {
      /* if length of A is less than 250 chars, read is no good, discard
      *  NOTE:  both Strings A and B will need to be validated for checksum
      * TODO check A & B if checksum is correct
      * */
      boolean _aOk = false, _bOk=false;
    
     short result = getCheckSum(A); 
     ...
     ...
```

Comment: Note that Java's `short` type is signed.

Comment: @Michael, thanks for that, will have to see if it causes me issues as I test and debug my app, only in the very early stages of a long haul journey to the end goal.